# Go how to properly use the for ... range loop

Tags: for-loop, go, range, slice

At the moment I have a go program that contains the following code.

```
package main

import "time"
import "minions/minion"

func main() {
    // creating the slice
    ms := make([]*minion.Minion, 2)

    //populating the slice and make the elements start doing something
    for i := range ms  {
        m := &ms[i]
        *m = minion.NewMinion()
        (*m).Start()
    }

    // wait while the minions do all the work
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

    // make the elements of the slice stop with what they were doing
    for i := range ms {
        m := &ms[i]
        (*m).Stop()
    }
}
```

Here `NewMinion()` is a constructor that returns a `*minion.Minion`

The code works perfectly, but having to write `m := &ms[i]` every time I use a `for ... range` loop seems to me like there should be a code writer friendlier way to tackle this problem.

Ideally I'd like something like the following to be possible (using the made up &range tag):

```
package main

import "time"
import "minions/minion"

func main() {
    // creating the slice
    ms := make([]*minion.Minion, 2)

    //populating the slice and make the elements start doing something
    for _, m := &range ms  {
        *m = minion.NewMinion()
        (*m).Start()
    }

    // wait while the minions do all the work
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

    // make the elements of the slice stop with what they were doing
    for _, m := &range ms {
        (*m).Stop()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not a language feature as of yet. Any considerations on what would be the nicest way remove the `m := &ms[i]` from the code? Or is there no way yet that takes less effort to write than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is a slice of pointers, you don't need to take the address of the pointers in the slice and then dereference the pointers each time. More idiomatic Go would look like (edited slightly to run in the playground without the "minion" package):

http://play.golang.org/p/88WsCVonaL

```
// creating the slice
ms := make([]*Minion, 2)

//populating the slice and make the elements start doing something
for i := range ms {
    ms[i] = NewMinion(i)
    ms[i].Start()

    // (or equivalently) 
    // m := MewMinion(i)
    // m.Start()
    // ms[i] = m
}

// wait while the minions do all the work
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

// make the elements of the slice stop with what they were doing
for _, m := range ms {
    m.Stop()
}
```

Comment: I indeed thought about that, but when you use ms[i] more then just 2 times, I thought it would be nicer to access the struct directly, in stead of accessing it through the slice all the time, because: A. you'd have to write brackets all the time, and B. In most languages accessing an element in an array takes (a tiny bit of) processing time afaik, which I therefore only want to do once. So in a sense, I'm trying to optimize both code writing time and processing time.

Comment: @coolcat007: You're optimizing very prematurely. If dereferencing pointers and memory locality make a measurable impact on your program, I think you can deal with the slight inconvenience of the extra index operation. Otherwise use a slice with pointers and get your code working. If you want to do more with the "minion" without indexing, just assign it to a variable and stick it in the slice when you're done: `m := NewMinion(i); ...; ms[i] = m`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That last suggestion is in my opinion the best solution to this problem. It also helps prevent the unnecessary use of pointers.

Comment: @coolcat007: I think you may have some misconception about pointers here, since my suggestion doesn't change the use of pointers at all, and is semantically equivalent. Manual dereferencing is rarely needed in Go; perhaps the relevant section of the spec on [Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) may clear things up.

Comment: No what I meant was that you only dereference the pointer once in `ms[i] = m`, in stead of dereferencing it multiple times when instantiating the struct and calling the function. However, in my first comment I had forgotten that accessing elements in an array is also basicly dereferencing. Or am I wrong on that last point?

Comment: @coolcat007: yes, you're wrong there. Assignment is *always* a copy (and everything in Go is passed by value). `ms[i] = m` is copying the value of `m` into `ms[i]`, and that value happens to be a pointer of type `*Minion` (if it were dereferenced, it would no longer be the correct type). Indexing into the slice gets you a pointer value back.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not really wrong, because I was aiming at the ms[i] part, not the actual assignment. Indeed assignment is always a copy, just like in C: you copy the value of the expression on the right (be it a native type/struct/(array)pointer to the variable on the left. And concerning the dereferencing: if in C `ms` is an array `ms[i]` would be the same as `*(ms + i)`. I don't know if this is also true for slices in Go though.

Comment: @coolcat007: that's not how slices work in go. It is similar in concept to arrays in Go, but Go has no pointer arithmetic. Note that even in C, dereferencing the array pointer is a separate step from dereferencing a pointer in an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is all wrong.

There is absolutely no need to take the address of a pointer in your code. `ms` is a slice of pointers and you constructor returns a pointer so just assign i directly:

```
for i := range ms  {
    ms[i] = minion.NewMinion()
    ms[i].Start()
}
```

Dead simple.

Comment: I presume you mean ms[i], not m[i]? Because m is not a slice